# OutOfMemoryError in Java file transferring in TCP

Tags: java, tcp, out-of-memory, file-transfer, lan

I designed a file-sender program and a file-receiver program in java, to learn about the TCP file transferring over a LAN.
My File-Sending Code is given below...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class filesender {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
InputStreamReader istream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(istream);
try
{
System.out.println("Receiver's I.P:");
String serverName = bufRead.readLine();
System.out.println("File Name:");
String filename = bufRead.readLine();
Socket Socket1 = new Socket(serverName, 6789);
DataOutputStream outToServer=new DataOutputStream(Socket1.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader go=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Socket1.getInputStream()));
File file = new File(filename);
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
byte sendData[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
fin.read(sendData);
outToServer.writeBytes(filename);
outToServer.writeInt(sendData.length);
outToServer.write(sendData, 0, sendData.length);
String deliveryreport = go.readLine();
System.out.println(deliveryreport);  /*Delivery report arrived from Receiver*/
Socket1.close();
}
catch (IOException err)
{ System.out.println("SENDER Error..!"); }}}
```

Well... my File-Receiver coding is given below...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class filereceiver {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
try
{
String filename;
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
System.out.println("Waiting on Port 6789...");
Socket conSocket = serverSocket.accept();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(conSocket.getInputStream());
BufferedReader hi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conSocket.getInputStream()));
DataOutputStream outToSender = new DataOutputStream(conSocket.getOutputStream());
int dataLength = dis.readInt();
byte[] receivedData = new byte[dataLength];
for(int i = 0; i < receivedData.length; i++)
receivedData[i] = dis.readByte();
filename = hi.readLine();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
fos.write(receivedData);
fos.close();
outToSender.writeBytes("File has been Sent..!");/*Delivery report to sender*/
System.out.println("File has been received..!"); /*Viewed on Receiver*/
serverSocket.close();
conSocket.close();
}
catch (IOException err)
{ System.out.println("RECEIVER Error..!"); }}}
```

O.K, These files were compiled executed correctly, but when I try to transfer a file, both programs give errors as below.

Sender Program given an IOException err /////////////"SENDER Error"////////////

Receiver Program said
//////////"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at filereceiver.main(filereceiver.java:17)////////////

Why these Errors occurred? Anybody could explain?

Comment: Indent your code, and start your class names with a capital letter. And you might want to print the stack trace instead of your own error message. Something like `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: It seems you first send the file name, and then the file length. Your receiver first tries to read the file length, but since you send the file name first, you'll interpret 4 bytes of the file name as the file length. That seems a bit backwards. (Note that you'll probably need to know the length of the filename too, otherwise you don't know how much to read to learn the file name.)

Comment: @KEYSER: Thanks Sir. It was succeeded when I let the "receiver to give a name for "received file"... The above coding tries to transfer the file without it's name-changing.

Comment: AN OutOfMemoryError means you try to allocate more memory than you have allowed your JVM.  Stream the file in parts at a time and you won't have this problem. There is many, many examples of how to do this.

Comment: BTW Don't mix text (Reader/Writer) and binary (Stream) unless you line confusion.  Don't read a file one byte at a time.  If you are going to read a file all at once, make you sure have enough memory do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line because you are trying to allocate the entire stream into RAM.

```
byte[] receivedData = new byte[dataLength];
```

When your stream is small, it is OK. But for big streams, allocate a small buffer (eg. 10K) and read it in chunks.

@nos also gave a comment about server writing the file name first, followed by the file length. You have to read it in the order that the data is written. But even after you read in the correct data, you will eventually have the problem I described. You definitely need to read data in chunks and process it as you go.

In addition, since you are sending the file name to the receiver, it is good to define a proper structure/header/protocol so that the receiver can easily process the incoming data. Here is a suggestion.

1. 1 byte to denote the file name length
2. following bytes are the actual file name
3. 8 bytes to denote length of contents of file.
4. following bytes are contents of file.

At the receiver end, you read first byte to know how many bytes to read for the file name. Then you read 8 bytes to know how many bytes to read for the contents.

Comment: To take this a step further, make sure you are writing the chunks out immediately.  If you read it in chunks and hold it in memory, you'll have the same problem, just later.

Comment: @jgitter, yes that is true.

Comment: A file length needs eight bytes, not four, otherwise +1.

Comment: @EJP, yes you are right to accommodate files greater than 4GB.

Answer (score -3):

Try to increase the heap memory on the receiver side using the JVM arguments like below,

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1g  -XX:PermSize=512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=1g
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  What happens when the file is larger than the size of your available memory?

Comment: @jgitter I agree your point. But is not the final solution. It's a combination along with increasing the heap memory. You can't leave with the default heap size if you know you want to handle large files.

Comment: Sure you can, you just have to handle them intelligently.  No matter how much memory you have, you will eventually have to handle data streams that are bigger.  You should buffer the data and back it with the disk.

Comment: Dear KEYSER, nos, Peter Lawrey, anonymous, jgitter, and Jay... I did it.  Through your responses, I've realized that "memory allocation has to be reduced". I closed the "conSocket" immediately after the file has been sent. Similarly I closed the "serverSocket" and "conSocket" just after the file has been re-written.
"The delivery report to sender from the receiver" also has been eliminated. Now the programs are running well...! But I'm not sure whether it gives troubles when I transfer some bigger files as you described above..! :) Anyhow I'll keep in mind your advise in future. Thanks again!